# Adjust height of ASCII art so that different graphics are printed in the same line

Tags: java, string

I want to print all wagons of a train in the same line.

Here is a code snippet that prints the train graphic which consists of different rolling stock.

```
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder trainGraphic = new StringBuilder();
        for (RollingStock rollingStock : train) {
            trainGraphic.append(rollingStock.toString());
        }
        return trainGraphic.toString();
    }
```

The easiest way to fix this would be to adjust the amount of lines for all wagons so that every ascii art has the same line amount. However, I would like to solve it a different way. How can I get the amount of lines of a ascii art so that I can adjust the height of all wagons to the highest amount of lines of the current train?

Here is the code that I use to print a wagon (in this case a DieselEngine):

```
        final String[] train = {
                "  _____________|____  ",
                " /_| ____________ |_\\ ",
                "/   |____________|   \\",
                "\\                    /",
                " \\__________________/ ",
                "  (O)(O)      (O)(O)  "
        };
        return String.join("\n", train);
```

For example, this wagon

```
         ++         
         ||         
_________||_________
|  ___ ___ ___ ___ |
|  |_| |_| |_| |_| |
|__________________|
|__________________|
   (O)        (O)
```

is higher than this one

```
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
|__________________|
   (O)        (O)
```

[image: Here]

Comment: My idea may have some unfamiliar code, but the gist of it is: each wagon is an array of strings, and the train is an array of wagons. Add some blank lines above the shorter wagons to make the printable height bigger, and it keeps the actual wagon height the same.

Comment: Okay, so I've edited my answer, and it solves everything except for printing the front of the train, but I feel you'd understand the concept better if you did it yourself. All the best :)

Comment: @RoboMop Please check my latest comment below your Answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I love your project, so I might have gotten carried away. Basically, you make train a double dimensional array (an array of arrays), with each element of `train` being a wagon. A wagon here is just an array of string, which contains the design.

I made a method to change the height of each wagon of the train, called `getHeightedArray()` (terrible name, I know).

Basically, you pass the height needed, then the array (wagon) to be changed.

Using some math, you can just add a blank `""` at the first few positions (heights) of the wagon, then you place all the existing design lines below the blank lines.

## TL;DR

You can put some blank lines above the design lines for each wagon array, thereby making its printable height taller, but its actual height is the same.

```
public static void main()
{
    String[] wagon1 = {
            "  _____________|____  ",
            " /_| ____________ |_\\ ",
            "/   |____________|   \\",
            "\\                    /",
            " \\__________________/ ",
            "  (O)(O)      (O)(O)  "
        };
    String[] wagon2 = {
            "         ++         ",
            "         ||         ",
            "_________||_________",
            "|  ___ ___ ___ ___ |",
            "|  |_| |_| |_| |_| |",
            "|__________________|",
            "|__________________|",
            "   (O)        (O)   "
        };

    String[][] train = {wagon1, wagon2, wagon1, wagon2};

    int max_height = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < train.length; i++)
    {
        String[] wagon = train[i];
        if(wagon.length > max_height)
        {
            max_height = wagon.length;
        }
    }

    //printTrain(train, max_height);

    for(int i = 0; i < train.length; i++)
    {
        train[i] = getHeightedArray(max_height, train[i]);
        train[i] = getWidthedArray(train[i]);
    }

    printTrain(train, max_height);
}

public static String[] getHeightedArray(int heightNeeded, String[] wagon)
{
    String[] return_arr = new String[heightNeeded];
    for(int i = 0; i < heightNeeded-wagon.length; i++)
    {
        return_arr[i] = "";
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < wagon.length; i++)
    {
        return_arr[i+heightNeeded-wagon.length] = wagon[i];
    }
    return return_arr;
}

public static String[] getWidthedArray(String[] wagon)
{
    String[] return_wagon = new String[wagon.length];

    int max_width = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < wagon.length; i++)
    {
        if(wagon[i].length() > max_width)
        {
            max_width = wagon[i].length();
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < wagon.length; i++)
    {
        return_wagon[i] = wagon[i];
        for(int j = 0; j < max_width-wagon[i].length(); j++)
        {
            return_wagon[i] += " ";
        }
    }
    return return_wagon;
}

public static void printTrain(String[][] train, int max_height)
{
    int heightOfConnector = 2; // 1 means the connector is at the wheel level, so I chose 2
    for(int i = 0; i < max_height; i++) // Controls the height, 0 means the top
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < train.length; j++) // Controls the wagon index
        {
            if(heightOfConnector == max_height-i && j != train.length-1)
                System.out.print(train[j][i]+" ++ ");
            else
                System.out.print(train[j][i]+"    ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

**Edit 1:** I am a dumbass, so the previous version of the code could not run due to some errors. The underlying principle is the same as what I've already said, but there were a few typos. My apologies.

`getWidthedArray()` ensures that the wagon is of uniform width throughout its body, and if not, you simply add spaces at the end of each of the uneven lines.

`printTrain()` is where the magic lies. You print the top layer of each wagon (separated by a few spaces), then the second-highest layer, and so on. If you're at the level specified by `heightOfConnector`, then you print `++` to indicate the connector. Feel free to adjust the height of the connector by the way.

Comment: I appreciate your help! However, I wasn't able to figure out how to return the modified graphic at the end. I tried ```return String.join(" ", train);``` but this won't work with a two-dimensional Array. Could you elaborate on that and show me how to print the final result as a String?

Comment: Definitely, and I can update the answer in a few hours. Is that alright?

Comment: Yeah, that's perfectly fine. Thank you very much!

Comment: Why do I need the method getWidthedArray()? The width is irrevlevant, isn't it?

Comment: Never mind, I just figured out why it's relevant. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but I still didn't figure it out completely. First of all, I don't understand why "System.out.println();" has to be executed maxHeight-times. Another problem I have is that I can only use a command from a different library which is Terminal.printLine(); <=> System.out.println(); . So I have to find another way to replace the System.out.print(..); in the printTrain() method. I tried to use a String (could also use a StringBuilder) and append train[j][i] + "++" for each wagon. Ultimately, I would print this String but this didn't work out as expected. Could you help me?

Comment: The appending to a String method seems like the correct answer. Create a String `newLine` for each printable line, and instead of `System.out.print(whatever)`, use `newLine += whatever`. Instead of `System.out.println()`, use `System.out.println(newLine)` . What wasn't working correctly from your code?